# Передача id от одной таблицы к другой. Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

У меня есть две таблицы: `customers` и `phoneNumbers`
У одного `customer` может быть 1+ `phoneNumbers`.

Нужно ли мне добавлять `OneToMany` анатацию, чтобы показывать, что у `customer` есть несколько номеров? Если да, то как?
Немного уточню: нужно ли добавлять `OneToMany`, чтобы `customer_id` передавался от `customer` в `phoneNumber`?

Диаграма сущности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
+-------------------------------+
|            customer           |
+-------------+-------+---------+
| customer_id | name  | surname |
+-------------+-------+---------+
|           1 | Alice | Rox     |
|           2 | Bob   | Ford    |
|           3 | ...   | ...     |
+-------------+-------+---------+

+-----------------------+
|     phoneNumbers      |
+-------------+---------+
| customer_id | number  |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 | +4456.. |
|           1 | +4474.. |
|           2 | +1871.. |
+-------------+---------+
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customers {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;
}
```

**PhoneNumbers.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "phoneNumbers")
public class PhoneNumbers {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "phone_id")
    private long id;

    private String number;
}
```

---

## Update 1

**PhoneNumber.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "phoneNumbers")
public class PhoneNumbers {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", nullable=false)
    private Customers customers;

    private String number;

}
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customers")
    private Set<PhoneNumbers> phone_id;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь следует правильно применить `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`
*Update. Данная вещь только для One-to-One возможна*

Теперь в таблице `phoneNumber` нужно убрать `id` и заменить его `customer_id`. Если я убераю строки в java связанные с ID, то мне выкидывает ошибку hibernate

Comment: *Нужно ли мне добавлять OneToMany анатацию, чтобы показывать, что у customer есть несколько номеров?* Нет. Количество номеров у customer, равно как и список customers, имеющих определённое количество телефонов (ни одного, один, не более одного, от 3 до 5, и т.п.), легко получить простым запросом.

Comment: *нужно ли добавлять OneToMany, чтобы customer_id передавался от customer в phoneNumber?* Да. Иначе как определить, чей телефон?

Comment: @Akina да, добавлять - это логично, но как? видел пример [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031199/hibernate-insert-table-id-as-foreign-key-in-another-table), но мне не подходит.

Comment: т.к. в данны примерах они выделяют в "основной таблице" дополнительную колонку, а мне этого не нужно

Comment: По первой ссылке - самое оно. Там cart, у тебя customer, там items, у тебя phoneNumbers. Вторую даже не смотрел.

Comment: @Akina сейчас добавлю пример кода. Проверьте его, пожалуйста, на правильность

Comment: Не-а. java/spring/hibernate/jpa не знаю от слова "ваще". Только SQL и логика.

Comment: @Akina тоже самое) С Hibernate недавно начал работать.

Comment: @Antonio112009, Вы должны решить, что будете делать сами, а что поручите Хибернейту. Если Вы ставите  OneToMany (кстати, сразу создайте private Set<PhoneNumbers> phone_id = new HasSet<>() и название phone_id путает -это же будит PhoneNumbers, а не их ID  ), Hibernate будет Вам автоматически загружать список телефонов, когда Вы запрашиваете Клиентов, Вы это можете увидеть в запросах, выводимых на консоль (в OneToMany fetch должен быть EAGER ). Также Hibernate может автоматизировать CRUD. Если Вы хотите сами этим заниматься, то не используйте OneToMany - Вы не обязаны это делать

Comment: @Orthodox желательно все поручить Hibernate. Вроде вопрос почти решен. Осталось только понять как заменить `id` на `customer_id`.

Comment: @Orthodox как на [этой диаграме](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779183/8992586)

Comment: Я плохо понял, что Вы ищете, но возможно Вам нужен referencedColumnName в JoinColumn

Comment: @Orthodox по скриншоту в **Update1** можно увидеть колонки `id` и `customer_id`. Мне требуется убрать `id` и вместо него сделать просто `customer_id`

Comment: В Column(name = "customer_id") заменить на id? Если здесь, то referencedColumnName="id" в JoinColumn не помогает?

Comment: @Orthodox 20 секунд

Comment: @Orthodox нет. Кидает ошибку(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91551/discussion-between-orthodox-and-antonio112009).